# Trouble finding the floor function of a given expression.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I am currently learning a bit about number theory - currently studying continuous fractions and came up with the following task:

**Task.** Show that the floor function of $$ \frac{n + \sqrt{n^2+4}}{2},$$ where $n$ is a positive integer, i.e., $n \in \Bbb N$ is $n$.

Obviously, the objective of this is to say that $ \frac{n + \sqrt{n^2+4}}{2} = [n; (...)]$, but I can't make this first step. How would one prove what's wanted?

I have tried doing it by induction and also tried squaring the expression, but couldn't find something that helped me.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: "$ \frac{n + \sqrt{n^2+4}}{2} = [n; (...)]$" : I am unsure what you intend by the $~\color{red}{[n; (...)]}~$ syntax.  For $~r \in \Bbb{R},~$ the $~\lfloor r\rfloor~$ syntax is used to indicate the largest integer $~\leq r.~$ Assuming that is your goal, for $~n \in \Bbb{Z^+},~$ you know that $~n^2 < (n^2 + 4) \implies n < \sqrt{n^2 + 4}.~$  Similarly, you also know that $(n^2 + 4) < (n^2 + 4n + 4) = (n+2)^2.$  So, a pertinent question to ask is: how does $~(n^2 +4)~$ compare to $~(n^2 + 2n + 1) = (n+1)~?~$ Further, given the denominator, you also have to question whether $n$ is odd or even.

Comment: @user2661923 That's exactly what I want! I will try understand your tips. The $[n;(...)]$ is a typical notation for continuous fraction that my teacher uses and it is not needed for the **task** in consideration. An example: $$ \frac{3}{2} = 1 + \frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow \frac{3}{2} = [1;2]$$

Comment: Do you *really* find the method in the accepter answer better than dividing its quadratic equation by $x$, as in my answer? The latter is not only shorter but makes it clear how to generate the continued fraction - which seems to be what you sought. Generally, when investigating quadratic numbers much can be deduced from their defining equations, so that is always a good place to start.

Comment: @BillDubuque Not necessarily better but for sure more self explaining for someone who comes to the forum and sees this question

Comment: @roro I think you may be missing something. How is it more "self explaining"? Using the quadratic formula we only need to divide by $x$ and we're done! (except for trivialities)

Comment: @BillDubuque One reason the accepted answer is better than your answer is that it actually contains full sentences and communicates what the OP can observe to understand their problem clearly. Your answer is (for reasons I do not understand) unnecessarily compacted and has exactly three words in it, one of which is abbreviated.

Comment: @Pedro Many of your prior comments have already made it quite clear that we strongly disagree on many subjective matters. There is no need to repeat yourself ad infinitum. Btw, curious that you arrived somehow  in this thread out of the blue ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The major observation is that the addition of $4$ does not increase the value of $n^2$ by very much—after taking square roots and dividing by $2$, this $+4$ contributes little to the term.  In more detail:

Observe that
$$ n^2 + 4 = (n+2)^2 - 4n, $$
where $4n > 0$ (since $n > 0$).  Then, as all of the relevant terms are positive,
\begin{align}
n^2 < n^2 + 4 < (n+2)^2
 &\iff n < \sqrt{n^2 + 4} < n+2 && \text{(take square roots)}\\
 &\iff 2n < n + \sqrt{n^2+2} < 2n + 2 && \text{(add $n$)} \\
 &\iff n < \frac{n+\sqrt{n^2+4}}{2} < n+1. && \text{(multiply by $\tfrac{1}{2}$)}
\end{align}
This is precisely what was desired.

Answer (score 1):

First we prove the following two properties of the square-root function:

> (1) For any positive real numbers $a$ and $b$, if $a < b$, then $\sqrt{ a} < \sqrt{b}$.

Proof:

> We note that, if $b > a > 0$, then $b-a > 0$ and $\sqrt{b} + \sqrt{a} > 0$, which implies that
> $$
> \sqrt{b} - \sqrt{a} = \frac{ \left( \sqrt{b} \right)^2 - \left( \sqrt{a} \right)^2 }{ \sqrt{b} + \sqrt{a} } = \frac{ b-a }{ \sqrt{b} + \sqrt{a} } > 0,
> $$
> and hence
> $$
> \sqrt{b} > \sqrt{a},
> $$
> as required.

Alternatively, we note that derivative of the function $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ for $x > 0$ is given by
$$
f^\prime (x) = \frac{ 1 }{ 2 \sqrt{x} } > 0,
$$
which implies that the square root function is strictly increasing.

Our second property is as follows:

> (2) If $a > 0$ and $b > 0$, then we have $\sqrt{ a+b} < \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}$.

Proof:

> As $a > 0$ and $b > 0$, so we have $a + b > 0$, and thus
> $$
> \sqrt{ a} + \sqrt{ b} + \sqrt{a + b} > 0
> $$
> also.
> Therefore we have
> $$
> \left( \sqrt{ a } + \sqrt{ b } \right) - \sqrt{ a+b } = \frac{ \left( \sqrt{ a } + \sqrt{ b } \right)^2 - \left( \sqrt{ a+b } \right)^2 }{ \sqrt{ a} + \sqrt{ b} + \sqrt{a + b}  } = \frac{ a + b + 2 \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b} - a - b}{ \sqrt{ a} + \sqrt{ b} + \sqrt{a + b} } = \frac{2 \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b} }{ \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} + \sqrt{ a + b}  } > 0, 
> $$
> which implies that
> $$
> \sqrt{ a } + \sqrt{ b } > \sqrt{ a+b}. 
> $$

Now we show that, for each $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$, we have
$$
n < \frac{ n + \sqrt{ n^2 + 4 } }{2} < n+1. 
$$
We note that
\begin{align}
n &= \frac{n + n}{2} \\ 
&= \frac{n + \sqrt{n^2} }{2} \\ 
&< \frac{ n + \sqrt{ n^2 + 4 } }{2} \qquad [\mbox{ because of our property (1) }] \\
&< \frac{ n + \sqrt{ n^2 } + \sqrt{ 4 } }{2} \qquad [\mbox{ because of our property (2) }] \\
&= \frac{ n + n + 2 }{2} \\
&= n+1.
\end{align}
Therefore we must have
$$
\left\lfloor \frac{ n + \sqrt{ n^2 + 4 } }{2}  \right\rfloor = n
$$
for each $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way: $\ \color{#c00}{x>1},\ \overbrace{x^2 = n\:\!x +1}^{\text{by quad. formula}}\,\underset{\!\!\div\,x}\Longrightarrow\, \overbrace{x = n + \frac{1}x}^{\large \color{#c00}{n\, <\, x \,<\, n+1\!\!\!\!\!\!}}\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{\lfloor x\rfloor = n}$

Comment: Note: viewing $\,x = n +\frac{1}{x}\,$ as a recurrence makes it clear how this is viewable as a special case of results on *continued fractions* (or closely related subjects).